# Issue with canDeactivate : "Type 'CanDeactivate' is not generic"

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

I am trying to set up a simple canDeactivate guard in Angular 7, and I have tried code from a number of online tutorials, but they all yield the same error:

> "Type 'CanDeactivate' is not generic."

What am I doing wrong? I can't even find this error on any google hits other than another 2 year old unanswered question with same issue.

See code here:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router/src/utils/preactivation';

export interface CanDeactivateComponent {
    canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanDeactivateComponent> {
    canDeactivate(component) {
        return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why are you importing CanDeactivate from @angular/router/sr/utils?

Comment: Not an Angular expert. Would help if you stated what version you are using.  However, your question took an interest in me as I like learning new frameworks.  I did find a blog with similar code than yours but has its differences.  Take a look here: https://scotch.io/courses/routing-angular-2-applications/candeactivate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `CanDeactivate` import is wrong. You have to import it from `@angular/router` like this:

```ts
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
```

This will export the right interface to use in your project. It is a generic interface with a type parameter for your component type:

```ts
export interface CanDeactivate<T> {
  canDeactivate(
      component: T, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
      nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean
      |UrlTree;
}
```

According to your import, the file [preactivation.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/utils/preactivation.ts) in the Angular repository exports an interface with the same name but whose usage seems to be internal to the angular library and not meant to be used outside of it:

```ts
export class CanDeactivate {
  constructor(public component: Object|null, public route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {}
}
```

This interface is not generic and has no type parameter, which is why you get an error when using it like this:

```ts
CanDeactivate<CanDeactivateComponent>
```